# AngularJS issue showing dynamic phrases according to a scope value.

Tags: angularjs, variables, scope

I have an issue. When people click on a link, this variable add 5 to the original value:

```
$scope.sumareco = function(cantidad) { $scope.contadoreco += cantidad};
```

If i print the value {{sumareco}} you can see how the value changes.

The problem starts when I create a conditional on the controller.

```
if ($scope.contadoreco < 30 && $scope.contadoreco > 10) {
        $scope.resultadoeco = "Opción uno";
    } else { 
        $scope.resultadoeco = "";
    }
```

If I print {{resultadoeco}} I expect that the phrase changes dinamically depending of the numeric value of $contadoreco. But it remains static and only shows the phrase assigned to the original value. ¿What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: What is the context for the `if` statement? If it's just sitting in your controller, it will only run once

Comment: Yes, is inside of the controller. So, what can I do make it work dinamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your `if` statement is just sitting in your controller and not inside any method or statement that would run during a digest cycle.

The easiest way to update `resultadoeco` is to *watch* `contadoreco`. For example

```
$scope.$watch('contadoreco', function(val) {
    $scope.resultadoeco = val > 10 && val < 30 ?
        'Opción uno' : '';
});
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch